# How to change DecorationRole shape to circle,except for using QIcon?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to add some round DecorationRole to QTableView, but this seems to be impossible.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()
        self._data = data

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            return QtGui.QColor('red') #change shape to circle

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return 'hi'
 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a QPixmap:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(96, 96)
            pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(pixmap)
            painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("red"))
            painter.drawEllipse(pixmap.rect())
            painter.end()
            return QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return "hi"

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return 4

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return 4


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    model = TableModel()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why does it seem that the resolution of QPixmap always feels blurry？

Comment: @Alex try again